# How to integrate Payment gateway with Magento 2 REST API?

Tags: magento2, payment, rest-api, magento-2.0

We are trying to build the generic android mobile app which can be used by magento 2 owners using REST API for Magento2 and have implemented the basic features for the app. As most of the people uses paypal for the payment gateway, we planned to use the paypal Android SDK for our mobile app but the problem is that we are not able to find the REST API to submit the transactionId or PaymentId to magento2. Do we need to write our own API for this or is there any existing rest API which we can use and submit the transactionId to magento2 store? Please help us.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link:

[How to add custom payment gateway extension in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121012/how-to-add-custom-payment-gateway-extension-in-magento2)

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/

https://magecomp.com/blog/create-custom-payment-method-in-magento-2/

I hope it will help you.