# How to add custom payment gateway extension in magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

1. Redirect to Payment Gateway and process payment
2. Return Back to store success page

Any help will be appreciated. I have followed the [Inchoo implementing a payment gateway tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/) But no luck.

Comment: The payment method with Adapter Class, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-custom-payment-method-using-adapter-class-magento-2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The common tutorial for adding custom payment integration is still in process, but you can use [sample-module-payment-gateway](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) as an example.

Also, [the off dev doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html) describes how to add a custom payment to the checkout page.

And a new implementation of [the Braintree](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree) payment method is a good example
of best practices for payment integrations.

**UPD**: Magento team has published [payments methods](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html) documentation.

Comment: Hi Joni, Can you please share idea how to redirect to payment gateway?

Comment: Depends on your integration, it can be simple redirect from browser or post redirect (like submit hidden form)