# Magento2: How to add a payment method to admin create order?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment

[image: Magento2 create order page]

I have an invoice payment method. The customer's call center should be able to create orders from backend and add this specific payment method to the order. The payment method is a gateway, which then creates the invoice to the finance company's system.

How do I implement this?

Comment: you have to add products first then you can see payment methods.

Comment: is it possible magento 1

Comment: Using Standard Way with Adapter Class, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-custom-payment-method-using-adapter-class-magento-2/

Answer (score 6):

At first, your payment method should be available for usage in Admin panel and you need to specify `can_use_internal` property in your payment method `YourCustomPayment/etc/config.xml` file:

```
<payment>
    <your_custom_payment_method_code>
        <model>YourCustomPaymentMethodFacade</model>
        ...
        <can_use_internal>1</can_use_internal>
    </your_custom_payment_method_code>
</payment>
```

On the next step, you need to create block class, depends on your integration it will extend `\Magento\Payment\Block\Form\Cc` or `\Magento\Payment\Block\Form`.

And, after block is created, you need to create template view for this block and specify it in the layout for billing form (`YourPayment/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml`):

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_create_billing_form">
        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate">
            <argument name="method" xsi:type="string">your_custom_payment_method_code</argument>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_YourCustomPayment::form/cc.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

And for `YourPayment/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_billing_method.xml`

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order.create.billing.method.form">
        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate">
            <argument name="method" xsi:type="string">your_custom_payment_method_code</argument>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_YourCustomPayment::form/cc.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

For more details, please, see my answer [How to add custom payment gateway extension in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121012/how-to-add-custom-payment-gateway-extension-in-magento2/121088#121088).

**UPD** [This](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/formblocktype.html) and [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/admin-integration.html) topics describe how to configure payment method for Adminl panel.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got this. I would need to trigger some actions (call to gateway, etc) after Submit order, how can I hook up?

Comment: @TeroLahtinen, please, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on `Magento 2.2.0`
I just added the `can_use_internal` flag in my `config.xml` file on `Magento 2.3.2` version and it's worked

[image: Can use internal flag]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in events.xml

```
 <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="disable_po" instance="Dev14\Replacements\Observer\PaymentMethod" />
    </event>
```

and in file use this code

```
<?php
namespace Dev14\Replacements\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class PaymentMethod implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_appState;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_appState = $appState;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        if(null !== $quote){
            if($method_instance->getCode() =='cashondelivery')
            {
                $result->setData('is_available',false);
            }
        }


    }

}
```