# Magento 2 - How to enable bank transfer only for admin order creation?

Tags: admin, magento2.3.4

We have only one online payment service for the customer, how to enable bank transfer only for admin order creation?

Comment: do u want to enable a bank transfer payment method in frontend or backend

Comment: Backend only not for Customer

Answer (score 3):

To enable a "payment method" only for admin can you please refer the below link

1. [Magento2: How to add a payment method to admin create order?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146946/magento2-how-to-add-a-payment-method-to-admin-create-order)
2. https://blog.e-zest.com/making-payment-method-visible-only-for-admin-in-magento-2

It's worked for me, Try the below one

> app/code/Gta/AdminPay/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Gta_AdminPay',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Gta/AdminPay/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Gta_AdminPay" setup_version="1.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Gta/AdminPay/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="gta_payment_filters" instance="\Gta\AdminPay\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Gta/AdminPay/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php

```
<?php
namespace Gta\AdminPay\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;     
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $this->_logger->info($method_instance->getCode());

        /* Enable All payment gateway  exclude Your payment Gateway*/
        if ($method_instance->getCode() == 'checkmo') {
            $result->setData('is_available', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $result->setData('is_available', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first point you shared second solution which file i need to edit for bank transfer

Comment: you need to create a di.xml file https://prnt.sc/uroaz3

Comment: After creating the module and enable Check / Money Order, It's showing on frond-end also. My module : app/code/Gta/AdminPay/etc/di.xml => https://justpaste.it/9jtbn, app/code/Gta/AdminPay/etc/module.xml => https://justpaste.it/2pupr, app/code/Gta/AdminPay/registration.php => https://justpaste.it/24mph, app/code/Gta/AdminPay/Plugin/Payment/Method/Checkmo/Available.php
 => https://justpaste.it/96fs0 Anything else i missed out?

Comment: After running the upgrade and static content deploy command still Check / Money Order display on front-end

Comment: Wait i will  post my code

Comment: Please refer the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113635/discussion-between-divya-sekar-and-zus).

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a payment option that is only available internally (admin area), we created an extension for that https://github.com/customgento/module-admin-payment-m2.