# Magento 2.3 - How to achieve can_use_internal for Check/Money order Payment Method?

Tags: magento2.3

I want to show Check/Money order Payment Method only for admin not for the website customers, how to achieve using can_use_internal. I am just trying Event observer

Event Observer:

app/code/Gta/AdminPay/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="payment_only_for_admin" instance="\Gta\AdminPay\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Gta/AdminPay/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Gta_AdminPay" setup_version="1.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

app/code/Gta/AdminPay/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php

```
<?php
namespace Gta\AdminPay\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;     
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $this->_logger->info($method_instance->getCode());

        if ($method_instance->getCode() == 'checkmo') {
            $result->setData('is_available', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $result->setData('is_available', true);
        }
    }
}
```

app/code/Gta/AdminPay/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Gta_AdminPay',
    __DIR__
);
```

Note: Hiding both frontend & backend, how to visible only on the backend?

Source : Thank you [Divya Sekar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/72237/divya-sekar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to use the checkmo payment method I think the cleanest way is to create a preference for \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Checkmo and override  canUseCheckout method and return false.

This way you do not have to write any observer or logic in it, it is already handled by Magento standard functionality.
It is also minimal code:

app/code/StackExchange/CheckMoney/Model/Checkmo.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchange\CheckMoney\Model;

class Checkmo extends \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Checkmo
{
    public function canUseCheckout()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

app/code/StackExchange/CheckMoney/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"
>
    <preference for="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Checkmo"
                type="StackExchange\CheckMoney\Model\Checkmo"
    />
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/CheckMoney/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_CheckMoney" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_OfflinePayments"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/CheckMoney/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_CheckMoney',
    __DIR__
);
```

The code above is tested and works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your initial explanation, and code help. I working on another task like PayPal payment only for a selected customer group. Can i get an idea to work this, i got confused about what should i go plugin or preference or event observer.

Comment: I guess plugin would be a good solution also instead of doing a preference, both will work. I am not so sure about observer, seems observers should be used in slighly different cases.

Comment: Is recommended to use Observer?

Comment: I think in this case it is not recommended to use an observer.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a minimal payment module tonight:

in etc folder, place a config.xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <dummy>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>Mbs\Payment\Model\Dummy</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Dummy Payment</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
            </dummy>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

then the Model that is in this config file is below:

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\Payment\Model;

class Dummy extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{
    /**
     * Payment method code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'dummy';

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isOffline = true;

    /**
     * Payment Method feature
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canUseCheckout = false;
}
```

what does the trick to be hidden in the checkout is the variable `$_canUseCheckout`

Happy to put the module fully but the rest is standard module that you likely know already

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout our module https://github.com/customgento/module-admin-payment-m2. It adds an internal payment method, only available and visible in the admin area.

Comment: I am getting an error during composer install https://snipboard.io/Js9vOF.jpg

Comment: Like i said in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323397/magento-2-how-to-enable-bank-transfer-only-for-admin-order-creation/323553?noredirect=1#comment464014_323553, check your Magento version. This module supports 2.3.* and 2.4.*

Comment: My Magento version 2.3.4?

Comment: How to solve the installation error?

Comment: I have open an PR to update the dependencies, will write as soon as they are merged. Should not take long

Comment: The changes have been merged, you can try to install the module again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114001/discussion-between-petar-borisovski-and-zus).

Comment: Getting error during install by using the composer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code works, change the observer like this to check area code as well.

app/code/Gta/AdminPay/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php

```
<?php
namespace Gta\AdminPay\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $state;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
     ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;     
        $this->state = $state;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $this->_logger->info($method_instance->getCode());

        if ($method_instance->getCode() == 'checkmo'
            && $this->state->getAreaCode() == 'frontend') {
            $result->setData('is_available', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $result->setData('is_available', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check / Money Order Display front-end also, how to restrict only for admin purpose?

Comment: Did you add the code I wrote ? It checks which area it is

Comment: My PaymentMethodAvailable.php : https://paste.ofcode.org/3b9DHfcHw9cVPtAqgLe37ze

Comment: Looks good, is it not working?

Comment: Yes, not working